# 14.04 - Old Firefox Version won't install, can't use profile manager

Tags: firefox, downgrade, .profile

I'm new to Ubuntu. (14.04)

Firefox comes default as version 31.x, but I need to use 29.0.1.

I've tried following multiple instructions, whereby copying an old firefox (old v29) to the usr/bin directory after unzippping it, thus overwriting the default version (v31). I can't seem to get everything working though.

The default version (v31) and old version (v29) run side by side, but opening the profile manager via the command line (firefox -p) just opens it via the new version (v31).

I need to completely remove the new version (v31) of firefox and just have the old version (v29), which I can then access the profile manager from the command line (so it's all v29).

Removing the new firefox installed by default (v31) via sudo apt-get remove firefox will stop 'firefox' being accessable in the terminal, despite the old version (v29) existing in usr/bin

I'm very confused and need some guidance.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 14.04? And would Firefox 28 suffice?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded it today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply download the Firefox Linux binary, unzip somewhere of your choice, give execute permissions to the binary file and launch it in a terminal.

You may create a .desktop file pointing to the chosen Firefox version giving it a different name (ex. Firefox 29) and save the file in `~/.local/share/applications/`

Thus you can run both versions of Firefox.

Be aware that they will share the profile folder unless you tweak the defaults.